# Whenever I call the class, I always get the same return of UIColor.White instead of whatever color I request

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, static-members

I am trying to make a class that holds relevant data for various graphical decisions we make for our app, and be able to make those changes in one location. However, whenever I call the class, I always get the same return of UIColor.White instead of whatever color I request. I do have this class in a Xamarin.iOS Library which I reference in the main project.

Here is a code sample:

```
public static class MyColors
{
    public static UIColor BackgroundColor
    {
        get { return ConvertHexToColor("fa0000"); }
    }

    public static UIColor ConvertHexToColor(string hex)
    {
        if (hex.Contains('#')) hex.Replace("#", "");
        int[] rgba = new int[] { 255, 255, 255, 255 };

        if (hex.Length == 6)
        {
            rgba[0] = Convert.ToInt32(hex.Substring(0, 2), 16);
            rgba[1] = Convert.ToInt32(hex.Substring(2, 2), 16);
            rgba[2] = Convert.ToInt32(hex.Substring(4, 2), 16);
        }
        else if (hex.Length == 8)
        {
            rgba[0] = Convert.ToInt32(hex.Substring(0, 2), 16);
            rgba[1] = Convert.ToInt32(hex.Substring(2, 2), 16);
            rgba[2] = Convert.ToInt32(hex.Substring(4, 2), 16);
            rgba[3] = Convert.ToInt32(hex.Substring(6, 2), 16);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Hash must be color code six or eight characters in length.");
        }

        return new UIColor(rgba[0], rgba[1], rgba[2], rgba[3]);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Well what debugging have you performed? Have you looked at the values of `rgba` just before the return statement?

Comment: What does your constructor look like? You could be sending correct values, but if your constructor logic isn't correct it may always create White.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have seen that the values that are in the array at the end of the method match the hex values put in [e.g. hex = "1e2426" -> rgba = { 30, 36, 38, 255 }]

Legion - It is a static class so it does not need a contructor.

Comment: True. But you call new UIColor(rgba[0], rgba[1], rgba[2], rgba[3]); What is it doing with those values?

Comment: Silly question maybe, but are they going to `UIColor` in the correct order? But then, I get 250, 0, 0, 255 - so it still wouldn't be "white"... are you sure the problem relates to *this* code?

Comment: @MarcGravell Yeah I double checked that the values being passed in were definitely not the color values of white, but I still get white.

Comment: @BlazePhoenix Did you try something like new UIColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) to see if you still get white? This way you can be sure the problem is in the ConvertHexToColor function.

Comment: @Legion just tried to run `return UIColor.Red;` and I still am returning white.

Comment: Looks like the problem is in your UIColor class and not the ConvertHexToColor function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the `UIColor` constructor accepts four (4) `System.Single` (`float`) values that needs to be between 0.0f and 1.0f - everything about will be considered as 1.0f.

If you want to use `byte` or `int` then use the static `FromRGBA` helper method.

Comment: I just took your solution into account, trying both `return UIColor.FromRGBA(rgba[0], rgba[1], rgba[2], rgba[3]);` and `return new UIColor(rgba[0] / 255.0f, rgba[1] / 255.0f, rgba[2] / 255.0f, rgba[3] / 255.0f);` and neither of those worked for getting the correct colors out.

Comment: The other part to the solution was to clean and build my project, rather than just rebuild. Thanks.